# jQuery live hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to convert the following into a live hover

```
$("li.favorite_item").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).append($(" <a href='#' class='button'>x</a>"));
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).find("a:last").remove();
    }
);
```

I've tried:

```
$("li.favorite_item"").live('hover', function() { 
    function () {
        $(this).append($(" <a href='#' class='button'>x</a>"));
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).find("a:last").remove();
    }
});
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From jQuery 1.7+ .live() is **[deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**, and .delegate() has been **[superseded](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)** by the .on() method.

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) in place of .live(), and .die().  Use .on() in place of .delegate().

Converting older code is straightforward [as explained here](http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/).

---

You need to call the events that [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) maps to separately, like this:

```
$("li.favorite_item").live('mouseenter', function() { 
  $(this).append($(" <a href='#' class='button'>x</a>"));
}).live('mouseleave', function () {
  $(this).find("a:last").remove();
});
```

[`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) isn't an event function like [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) is for example, it's [just a special shortcut for `.mouseenter(handler1).mouseleave(handler2)`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/event.js#L994-996)...so you need to do the same in your [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) call.

If you're on jQuery 1.4.3+, you can use a map to simplify things, like this:

```
$("li.favorite_item").live({
  mouseenter: function() { 
    $(this).append($(" <a href='#' class='button'>x</a>"));
  },
  mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).find("a:last").remove();
  }
});
```

Also, if this is on a specific `<ul>`, [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is a better option, like this:

```
$("#myUL").delegate("li.favorite_item", {
  mouseenter: function() { 
    $(this).append($(" <a href='#' class='button'>x</a>"));
  },
  mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).find("a:last").remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The .live() syntax was nicer, but we have to use .on(), now.

You can use an event map on the document, with the selector as the 2nd argument:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).append("<a href='#' class='button'>x</a>");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).find("a:last").remove();
    }
}, "li.favourite_item");
```

Answer (score -1):

**this is true...**

```
$("#your_div_id").live('mouseover',function(){

    $(this).find(".child_div").css('background-color','#111111');

}).live('mouseout',function(){

     $(this).find(".child_div").css('background-color','#757575');
});
```