# jQuery hover live()?

Tags: jquery, hover, live

I'm learning jQuery and I'm not sure how to "inform" the script that something had happened.

For example, when I hover a .container it adds "grey" class to it. But when I want to do anything with the newly created "grey" div, then nothing works. I've heard about live() function, but I'm not sure that's the good way?

```
   jQuery('.container').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).animate({opacity: '0.5'},1000);
        jQuery(this).addClass('grey');
    });

    jQuery('.grey').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).animate({opacity: '0'},100);
    });
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/n5kpM/

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jQuery 1.7+ .live() is **[deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**, and .delegate() has been **[superseded](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)** by the .on() method.

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) in place of .live(), and .die().  Use .on() in place of .delegate().

Converting older code is straightforward [as explained here](http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/).

---

`live` is exactly what you want.  Since the `.grey` element doesn't exist at the time you are calling `hover`, it will not work the way you have it.  Using `live` will let you apply the handlers before the element exists.

One thing to note though, you can't use `live` directly with `hover`.  You need to do the 2 events separately.  [jQuery live hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450125/jquery-live-hover)

Answer (score 2):

`live` is called like this:

```
$(...).live('mouseenter', function() { ... });
```